# Javascript page refresh based on current time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some javascript that constantly checks for the current second of the time and if it matches a certain second value to refresh the page and continue doing that, so my page will always refresh at specified second intervals based on the current time. For example: 3:01:10 PM, 3:01:15 PM, 3:01:20 PM, 3:02:10 PM, etc.

My code below doesn't seem to be working - any ideas how I could accomplish this? Thanks!

```
var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
setTimeout(function(){
if (seconds == 10 || seconds == 15 || seconds == 20) {
    window.location.reload(1);
}
}, 1000);
```

Comment: put `var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();` inside the `setTimeout`.

Comment: pls. notice that JS is using client time - it can be various

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the value of `second` exactly one time with your code. You need to move the variable within the function and change [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    if (seconds == 10 || seconds == 15 || seconds == 20) {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you never update the value of "seconds". Try moving it into the function.

```
var seconds;
setTimeout(function(){
seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
if (seconds == 10 || seconds == 15 || seconds == 20) {
    window.location.reload(1);
}
}, 1000);
```